# Can't add Google account, the browser window is corrupted

Tags: raspberrypi, 21.04, google-drive

I just installed Ubuntu on my Raspberry Pi 4 from the official image (for rPi). Everything seems to work just fine, except for the Google login window (and the other online accounts as well).

Any idea how to fix this / work around this?

[image: Corrupted login window]

EDIT: There is a warning in the console: "GDK is not able to create a GL context, falling back to glReadPixels (slow!)"

Comment: Is your system fully updated? If not, please update it and retry.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Yes, fully updated.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem.  Switching from wayland to xorg fixed it.